Generating context for Questions and Answers
General problem overview:
I need to fine tune question answering model to extract answers to questions from ~5 page documents but I only have pairs of questions and answers, no context.
The documents are unstructured text that each contains answers to ~20 questions + some unimportant text. All documents have very similar topic (they are all Data Management Plans). Both questions and answers are generally at least one sentence long.
Example of a questions and answers:

Q: What types and formats of data will the project generate/collect?


A: As such the list of types and formats of data generated is long, and includes but is not limited to: Formatted/unformatted text Mov MP4 Binary HDF5 Xlsx Jpg VTK PDB PSF PRMTOP XTC PDF PNG EPS DICOM C3D VTK



Q: What is the origin of the data?


A: The data originates from many different sources. Non-simulation data, used to build models generally, can originate from clinical data management systems or DICOM image stores."


See more questions here (there are more than just these questions, but all are similar to this).
Available data
My dataset consists of questions and answers (around 10 thousand pairs), I need to generate a context to finetune a question answering model.
I also have ~1000 unlabelled documents with free text each containing answers to around 20 questions each. My goal is to train model for extraction of answers from documents like these (I have some labelled documents I will use for evaluation, but not enough to train).
Question:
How can I generate context by taking my answer as input and surrounding it with text that resembles my target document while still knowing where the answer is.
